# Найти в файле по id пользователя и заменить его значения. Поиск по id выполнил.Может кто-нибудь помочь с заменой значений?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        UsersRepository usersRepository = new UsersRepositoryFileImpl("users.txt");
        List<User> users = usersRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("Введите ID пользователя: ");
        List<User> users2 = usersRepository.findById(scanner.nextInt());

        for (User user : users2) {
            System.out.println(user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getAge() + " " + user.isWorker());
        }
    }
}

public interface UsersRepository {
    List<User> findAll();
    List<User> findById(int Id);
    List<User> update(User user);
}

public class UsersRepositoryFileImpl implements UsersRepository {
    private String fileName;

    public UsersRepositoryFileImpl(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        // объявили переменные для доступа
        Reader reader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            // создали читалку на основе файла
            reader = new FileReader(fileName);
            // создали буферизированную читалку
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            // прочитали строку
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            // пока к нам не пришла "нулевая строка"
            while (line != null) {
                // разбиваем ее по |
                String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
                // берем Id
                int Id = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                // берем имя
                String name = parts[1];
                // берем возраст
                int age = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                // берем статус о работе
                boolean isWorker = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[3]);
                // создаем нового человека
                User newUser = new User(Id, name, age, isWorker);
                // добавляем его в список
                users.add(newUser);
                // считываем новую строку
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } finally {
            // этот блок выполнится точно
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    // пытаемся закрыть ресурсы
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    // пытаемся закрыть ресурсы
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            }
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findById(int Id) {
        List<User> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User u : findAll()) {
            if (u.getId() == Id) {
                filtered.add(u);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Такой записи не существует");
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    @Override
public void update(User user) {
    Writer writer = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        bufferedWriter.write(user.getId()+ "|"+ user.getName() + "|" + user.getAge() + "|" + user.isWorker());
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
        if (bufferedWriter != null) {
            try {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализация очень сложная , мало того, ваш интерфейс и его имплементация некорреткны. В целом понятие айди говорит о его уникальности, а у вас, исходя их сигнатуры методов, айди - непонятно что (там метод поиска по айди список возвращает, этого не может быть в природе). Кроме того, операции чтения/записи в файл производятся проще, а операцию чтения не стоит заталкивать в метод findall, ведь чтение с файла - не самая быстрая операция.
В целом попробуйте для начала сделать так:

```
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            UsersRepository usersRepository = UsersRepository.of("users.txt");
            System.out.println("Введите ID пользователя: ");
            Optional<User> user = usersRepository.findById(scanner.nextInt());        
            if (user.isPresent()) System.out.println(user);
            else System.out.println("Такой записи не существует");        
        }
        
    }
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    public interface UsersRepository {
    
        Collection<User> findAll();
    
        Optional<User> findById(Integer id);
    
        User update(User user);
        
        void save() throws IOException;
    
        static UsersRepository of(String fileName) {
            return new UsersRepositoryFileImpl(fileName);
        }
    
    }
    
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    
    public class UsersRepositoryFileImpl implements UsersRepository {
    
        private final Map<Integer, User> users;
        
        private final String fileName;
    
        public UsersRepositoryFileImpl(String fileName) {
            this.users = read(fileName);
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }
    
        private Map<Integer, User> read(String fileName) {
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
                return stream
                        .map(User::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, user -> user, (k1, k2) -> k1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public Collection<User> findAll() {
            return users.values();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Optional<User> findById(Integer id) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(users.get(id));
        }
    
        @Override
        public User update(User user) {
            return users.put(user.getId(), user);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void save() throws IOException {
            Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), users.values().stream()
                    .map(User::toTextLine)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")).getBytes());
        }
    
    }
    
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Boolean isWorker;

    public User(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        this.name = parts[1];
        this.age = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        this.isWorker = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[3]);
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Boolean isIsWorker() {
        return isWorker;
    }

    public void setIsWorker(Boolean isWorker) {
        this.isWorker = isWorker;
    }
    
    public String toTextLine() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append(id).append("|")
                .append(name).append("|")
                .append(age).append("|")
                .append(isWorker)
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", isWorker=" + isWorker + '}';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, после `update` надо сохранить в файле изменения, сейчас они просто сохраняются в памяти

Comment: @Alex Rudenko не могу сказать, в задаче об этом ничего не сказано. думаю, что если с этим возникнут проблемы, то автор вопроса об этом напишет, хотя я не понимаю, какие проблемы могут вознинкуть с записью в файл. это гуглится за 15 секунд и даже менять ничего не придется...

Comment: @AlexRudenko ,да после update надо сохранить в файле изменения,затерев старые значения.

Comment: @Антон Михайлов так в чем именно теперь проблема?

Comment: @Дмитрий никак не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: @Антон Михайлов простите, а что вы сделали, чтобы понять? если потратить ровно 20 секунд набить в гугл набор слов в гугл "java write to txt file" по любой ссылке найдете по несколько примеров кода, который даже править не придется.  просто копируете , добавляее метод в свой сервис.

Comment: @Дмитрий Добавил свою реализацию,но есть сомнения в правильности работы.

Comment: @Антон Михайлов вариант имеет право на жизнь, но проблема все та же: слишком сложная реализация для такой простой задачи. Кроме того, операция чтения/записи в файл - достаточно ресурсозатратная и медленная (о чем я уже писал). В связи с этим выполнять обновление и сохранение в одном методе - плохая идея (я уже молчу про первый принцип SOLID). если этот функционал (обновление-запись) разделить, то обновлять вы можете множество записей подряд, а запись произвести лишь единожды. Ответ я изменил, добавив метод сохранения в файл. Удачи